# nothing provides libpython2.7.so.1.0()

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, azure

I have installed python 2.7 in SLES11 SP4 machine. The installation path is `/opt/python2.7`. The library `libpython.so.1.0` is available at `/opt/python2.7/lib/`.

I have configured this in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opt-python2.7.conf`.

I checked whether the library is present or not with `ldconfig -p | grep libpython2.7`. And this gives following result:

    `libpython2.7.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
    libpython2.7.so (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so`

So I believe linux is able to locate the library correctly.

However, whenever I try to install one package using `zypper in azure-cli` it gives the following error every time:

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by azure-cli-2.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install azure-cli-2.0.26-1.el7.x86_64
 Solution 2: break azure-cli-2.0.26-1.el7.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): 1
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving package dependencies...
```

I am not understanding, why it is not able to get this library.

Comment: Have you installed Python via source or using a package manager?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Narrow your issue to installing cryptography, my two cents it's the guy that creates you trouble.

Comment: @LaurentMazuel I am not trying to install cryptography. I just want to install python 2.7 in my machine SLES11 SP4. So that I can install azure-cli to run azure commands from this machine.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I installed it by building source.

Comment: @JaydeepRanipa CLI requires cryptography in order to work... That was my point only.